# How to execute API's parallelly using Angular

Tags: angular, angular-datatables

Have multiple datatables on same page, every page have different APIs and params. Once we click on load button need to execute APIs parallel and populate the datatables. Could you please suggest me how to implement parallel execution, here is the sample code,

API - 1

```js
     const dataUrl1 =
          "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/l-lin/angular-datatables/master/demo/src/data/data.json";
        this.http.get(dataUrl1).subscribe(response => {
          this.persons = response.data;
          this.dtTrigger1.next();
        });
```

API - 2

```js
        const dataUrl2 =
          "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/l-lin/angular-datatables/master/demo/src/data/data.json";
        this.http.get(dataUrl2).subscribe(response => {
          this.persons = response.data;
          this.dtTrigger2.next();
        });
```

Stackblitz: [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-datatables-gitter-e129uz)

Comment: By default and their nature, HTTP requests in Angular (using its `HTTPClient`) are non-blocking and observable based.

Comment: Parallel or one after another

Comment: Parallel execution. One after another taking time to load tables.

Comment: Http requests are asynchronous tasks, you dont need to do anything in order to run them parallel

Answer (score 0):

It's parallel by default.
If you need to make the calls in parallel and get the response together you can think of using rxjs operators like - forkJoin, zip

If you need to use one after other, use mergeMap, switchMap

Comment: On other option is,  you using promises you can also use Promise.all the wait for all request.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use **forkjoin** the Rxjs operator dedicated for these types of use cases :

```
     ngOnInit() {
    let apiCall1 = this.http.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/l-lin/angular-datatables/master/demo/src/data/data.json');
    let apiCall2 = this.http.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/l-lin/angular-datatables/master/demo/src/data/data.json');

    forkJoin([apiCall1, apiCall2]).subscribe(results => {
      // results[0] is our apiCall1 result
      // results[1] is our apiCall2 result
   
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If data in a single datatable is dependent on multiple APIs, you need to execute all those dependent apis in parallel and get their response at the same time so that it'll be easy to load the datatable. One can achieve this either with `forkJoin` or with `combineLatest`. However, `forkJoin` is more suited for this scenario.

e.g.

```
const api1$ = this.http.get('url1');
const api2$ = this.http.get('url2');

const result$ = forkJoin([api1$, api2$]);

result$.subscribe(([res1, res2]) => {
  // do your stuff and load the datatable
})
```

If you have multiple data tables where there's a one to one relation between datatable and  API, you can directly call the apis using `http.get` and then subscribe to them without any need of additional operators.

e.g.

```
this.http.get('url1').subscribe((res1) => { // load the datatable 1 });
this.http.get('url2').subscribe((res2) => { // load the datatable 2 });
```

Both these calls will execute in parallel as pointed out in the comments.